# When should I make edits to code?

Tags: discussion, editing

Our current Help Center->Our Model [page](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/editing) gives the following guidance on **edits**.

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of    the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

**When should I make edits to code?**

What are the guidelines for editing someone else's code in a

- Question?
- Answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the StackOverflow [canonical answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/8239061) on this is useful (excerpts below).

> ## Editing Code in Questions
>
> Code in questions should only be edited for formatting and
>   readability. Editing the syntax or correcting typos in code in
>   questions can fix the problem that the person asking the question has,
>   causing answers to be unable to address the problem.
>
> #### Do:
>
> - Add [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) around code
> - Add indentation
> - Add line breaks
> - Improve the title to match the question content
> - Edit tags to match the question
> - Fix any spelling/grammar errors outside of the code block
> - Fix Syntax (non-closed brackets, missing semi-colons, etc.), **unless they are relevant to the question**
> - Fix typos (misspelled function calls, variable names, etc.), **unless they are relevant to the question**
>
> #### Don't:
>
> - Change code conventions (`delimited_names` to `camelCase` names, etc.)
> - Change the code logic or functionality
> - Fix or change the problem that's being asked about
> - Copy code from a linked site into the question <sup>[1][1], [2][2]</sup>
> - Transcribe code from an image to text. It's just too easy to introduce new errors.
> - Ignore improvements that can be made outside the code block (spelling, grammar, etc.)
>
> ## Editing Code in Answers
>
> Answers are intended to be resources for future visitors. While [quick
>   and dirty answers are useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758),
>   they may have errors in syntax due to being typed in without being
>   checked first, and could have room for improvement. Unlike questions,
>   making an answer work is a good thing and should be encouraged with a
>   few guidelines to follow.
>
> #### Do:
>
> - Test your edited code to make sure it works
> - Fix syntax errors and typos
>      If changing the syntax errors or typos would result in the code doing something other than what the answer says it will, consider
>     creating a comment or a separate answer explaining your change. If
>     posting another answer with only that change seems like it won't
>     provide added value to future visitors, it probably doesn't change
>     logic or functionality and should be an edit instead.
> - Improve formatting
> - Correct spelling/grammar issues in the answer body
>
> #### Don't:
>
> - Change code conventions (`delimited_names` to `camelCase` names, etc.)
> - Make the code do something different than what the answer says it does
> - Ignore improvements that can be made outside the code block (spelling, grammar, etc.)